# Android 11 URI usage (file:// content://)

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-fileprovider, android-11

We have some old issues with similar words, but most of them are about converting one or the other.

What I'm looking here is the "Right" behaviour of URI usage with the new changes. Let me give some context:

**Before** when we get an image URI this would return `file://...` format.
But since the new OS permissions changes, where we should not use `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` anymore we should use `getUriForFile(..)` that return `content://...` path.(Scope Storage usage [Android 11 Storage FAQ](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-11-storage-faq-78cefea52b7c))

This can be spot on some Android guides, like:  [taken photos guide](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)

The "problem" is that many users got used to use the URI of a crop image (for example) to create a file of it and save it.

Now, with this changes come the question:

**How should we use the URI?**

1. Make some code to check Android version and if more than 29 we should create a new file path for the URI?
2. Let the URI be the path to the image (`content` of `file`) and if someone wanna save it would need to create it own file path
3. Something else that I don't get yet about how to use URI right.

Obs: Asking this, because of a Android Image Crop open source project handover, where we need to upgrade the permissions for Android 10/11 but now we have this content/file issue. [More here](https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/discussions/87#discussioncomment-543259)

**Edit**:
As pointed on the comments

Code returning `file://` (not valid anymore since the changes)

```java
Uri outputFileUri = null;
outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(
                  new File(context.getExternalCacheDir().getPath(), 
                  "pickImageResult.jpeg")
                );
```

Code returning `content://`

```kotlin
outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        context,
                        context.getPackageName() + CommonValues.authority,
                        File.createTempFile("pickImageResult", ".jpeg", getImage)
                );
```

Comment: "Before when we get an image URI this would return file://... format" -- not generally. Could you add an [mcve] to explain what you are doing?

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare I add some code. Sadly this is very very complex to add a full example, even minimal would need camera, take a picture and crop, for example. In both cases. I know that makes harder to help like this, but this became a common issue for anyone dealing with images lately. Can see in Android-Image-Crop or uCrop libraries. But the issue is solve in the sense of new Android. The question now is what "URI" should represent?

Comment: "when we get an image URI this would return file://... format" -- what is "returning" this? Your code snippet is *creating* a `file://` `Uri`. You are welcome to do that and use it purely within your own app -- nothing has changed with Android 11 in that regard. "we should use getUriForFile(..) that return content://... path" -- use for what? "many users got used to use the URI of a crop image (for example) to create a file of it and save it" -- how is an end user getting a `Uri`?

Comment: "How should we use the URI?" -- use it for *what*? Overall, your question here seems to make a lot of assumptions that we know exactly what you are doing with these `Uri` values. Not only does that make it difficult for us to help you with your problem, but it reduces the value of your question to the millions of Stack Overflow users.

Comment: @CommonsWare with Android 11 we should not use `context.getExternalCacheDir().getPath()` anymore. Because of this we change from `Uri.fromFile` (that returns file://)  to `FileProvider.getUriForFile` (that returns content://). This way we use Scope Storage like Google/Android suggestion. My point is exactly your latest comment. What URI should be used for? Because before people used to create files, but changing from `file to content` make this not trivial anymore. What is the right way of using URI?

Comment: "with Android 11 we should not use context.getExternalCacheDir().getPath() anymore" -- in your own app, you most certainly can use `getExternalCacheDir()`. " Because of this we change from Uri.fromFile (that returns file://) to FileProvider.getUriForFile (that returns content://)" -- `Uri.fromFile()` has been banned for five years. This is nothing new, and is only relevant if you are trying to create a `Uri` to pass to another app. Since I have no idea what you are doing with your `Uri`, I have no idea if you are trying to pass it to another app or not.

Comment: The open source library just return the URI and each developer can do whenever they prefer. Like the link on the description, one case is that Devs was using the URI to save a file, but now URI return `content://` so they cannot use as file anymore. They would need to create a new file a copy from the URI. Is this the intent of URI? or should I change the library to return a valid `file` path? Like this user: https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/84

Comment: Personally? I would think that your library should not be setting up `FileProvider`. Your library is for cropping images, not for sharing content between apps. Users of your library should be setting up that content sharing themselves, so that they control how it works. If you want to keep returning a `Uri`, that could still be based on `Uri.fromFile()`, so long as you document that the `Uri` that you return is for in-app use and is not designed for passing to another app. Or, change the API to return a `File`. But, in the end, that's all your decision to make.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the vision, maybe this is the main issue. Would be great to improve this and even remove the need for the permissions of the library. I wanna thank you for the time to take a look on this. I didn't know about CommonsWare before, just sent a e-mail hope we can setup a mentor process =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The "problem" is that many users got used to use the URI of a crop image (for example) to create a file of it and save it.

In the end, this is your library, and you need to document what any `Uri` that you return is suitable for. After all, a `Uri` could point to:

- A file on the filesystem (`file`)
- A Web resource (`https`, or possibly `http`)
- An Android resource (`android.resource`)
- An asset in the app (`file://android_asset`)
- Some arbitrary set of bytes (`content`)

Your library is for image cropping. While I have not examined the implementation, I assume that it all works inside the app itself. If so, there is nothing wrong with returning a `file` `Uri`, if you want to do so. Your code is writing a file somewhere (e.g., `getCacheDir()` on `Context`). The app using your library must have access to that file, or else you would have crashed trying to write it. A `Uri` created via `Uri.fromFile()`, for that file, is perfectly fine... in that app.

Where `Uri.fromFile()` becomes a problem is in passing the `Uri` to another app. However, your library is for cropping images, not sharing content with other apps. Your job, IMHO, is to give a cropped image back to the app. What the app does with it is up to that app, subject to whatever limitations there are in the `Uri` that you hand over.

The two options that you seem to be considering have different issues:

| `Uri` Source | Advantages | Disadvantages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Uri.fromFile()` | Cheap, easy | Can only be used within the app itself; cannot be passed to other apps |
| `FileProvider` | `Uri` can be passed to other apps | Requires a library and manifest configuration; cannot readily get to the underlying file |

Since IMHO an image cropper is not an image *sharing* solution, `Uri.fromFile()` seems reasonable. If the app using your library wants to turn around and share the cropped image, they would set up `FileProvider` themselves and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`. The only catch is that either you need to document where the file will be written or give them an option to tell you what directory to use — that information will be needed to set up the `FileProvider` metadata.

Someday, if you elect to change the API, you might consider returning an ordinary `File` instead of a `Uri`. That way, there is no confusion about what it represents.

But, in the end, this is all your decision. If you want to use `FileProvider`, or you want to upload images to your own Web server and use `https`, that is all up to you. However, you should document what you are doing and what the `Uri` represents.